# How do I remove space inside div in html and css?

Tags: html, css

I have one div inside and some images. When I give a margin for the image of 10px it applies to all sides. What I want to happen is to remove the spacing around the image closest to the div side.

I mark some red areas where I want space removed:

[image: I mark some red area where I want space removed]

```css
.soot {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

.imgbox {
  `` width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgbox">
  <div class="show">
    <img class="soot soot1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="show">
    <img class="soot soot4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot6" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="show">
    <img class="soot soot7" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot8" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot9" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Remove space inside the div where the images must be set having no space around outer the ones.

Comment: Then remove the margin, which you set in the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use margins for the images. Use the gap property instead!

However, the easiest way is not to use flexbox here. What you want here is CSS-Grid. CSS-Grid can also make usage of the `gap` property:

```css
.soot {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.imgbox {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgbox">
  <img class="soot soot1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="soot soot2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="soot soot3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="soot soot4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="soot soot5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="soot soot6" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="soot soot7" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="soot soot8" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="soot soot9" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

If you insist on using Flexbox, then still remove the margin from the images and apply the gap property correctly. The issue or difficulty here is, that you manually need to calculate the correct width of the images:

```css
:root {
  --gap: 20px;
  --columns: 3;
}

.imgbox {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.show {
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.soot {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  width: calc((100% - (var(--gap) * (var(--columns) - 1))) / var(--columns));
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgbox">
  <div class="show">
    <img class="soot soot1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="show">
    <img class="soot soot4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot6" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="show">
    <img class="soot soot7" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot8" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot9" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the white spaces on the sides and add top/bottom margin you can use `{margin: 20px 0;}` on the row container i.e. **.show**.
For removing the top and bottom spaces you have to remove the top margin from the first row and bottom margin from last row. I've used `.show:first-Child{}` and `.show:last-Child{}` for this. Use `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` so that the margin and  padding don't mess up the image-size which is set to **33.3%** (avoiding overflow and useless calculations for proper sizing). Also, the first and second image will have padding-right, use `.soot:nth-Child(1), .soot:nth-Child(2) {padding-right:20px}`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.imgbox {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.show:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.show:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.soot {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 400px;
}

.soot:nth-child(1),
.soot:nth-child(2) {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgbox">
  <div class="show">
    <img class="soot soot1" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/coding/600" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot2" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/coding/600" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot3" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/coding/600" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="show">
    <img class="soot soot4" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/coding/600" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot5" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/coding/600" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot6" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/coding/600" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="show">
    <img class="soot soot7" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/coding/600" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot8" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/coding/600" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot9" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/coding/600" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a task for padding nor a margin! You have a dedicated property for that: `gap`. Beyond that, the padding (actually margins)  are 20px not 10px. `calc(100% / 3)` will be more accurate than `33.3%` while also using padding to enlarge an image beyond its actual size to bypass calculations is not a correct solution.

Comment: I understand that but using gap he is going to have to change a lot of things. You have to keep his setup in mind as well. I would prefer to use gird instead in such a case but that's not the point here. and gap value you can set to whatever he wants.  I would have used a custom variable for padding here to keep modification convenient.

Comment: using gap does not require changing his setup (markup). But overall this is a learning site. You just don patch the code of beginners by adding more unclean solutions to it. You show them how to program correctly in the first place so they don't have the issues they are facing at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use grid, just add a separate class to every picture and then only add margins to the sides that aren't next to the border ex. margin-left: 10px.

```css
 .soot {
      width: 33.3%;
      height: 400px;
      margin: 10px; /*remove the margin from here*/
      border: 2px solid yellow;
    }

    .soot1 {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="imgbox">
  <div class="show">
    <img class="soot soot1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score -1):

if i understand well

```
  .imgbox .show:first-child .soot {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
  }
  .imgbox .show:last-child .soot {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
  .imgbox .show .soot:first-child {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
  .imgbox .show .soot:last-child {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
  }
```

Comment: no reason to use `!important` here. But also isn't a real solution but more like a cover-up to fix a wrongly applied property instead of using the correct property in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.soot {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;

}

.imgbox {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
width: max-content;
position : absolute

}

.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgbox">
  <div class="show">
    <img class="soot soot1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="show">
    <img class="soot soot4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot6" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="show">
    <img class="soot soot7" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot8" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="soot soot9" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: removing all spaces including between the images was not the thing the OP asked for.

Comment: If you want to correct formatting in the question, then suggest and edit using the "Edit" link on a post